# how to get twitter trending topics on button click android - twitter4j?

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I've been studying android for a small period of time, and i'm trying to put some twitter functions in to my apps.

What i'm trying to do is get the twitter trending topics and put it on a String, and then display them on a textview. Is it possible? I found almost nothing on the internet, so hope you can help me.

`

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_trending);


    getTrendingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gettrendingbutton);
    trendingList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.trendinglist);



    cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setApplicationOnlyAuthEnabled(false);
    cb.setOAuthConsumerKey("key")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("key")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("key")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("key");

    twitterFactory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();


}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    getTrendingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String trendsString = " ";
            Trends trends;
            try {
                trends = twitter.getPlaceTrends(1);
                int count = 0;
                for (Trend trend : trends.getTrends()) {
                    if (count < 10)
                    {
                        trendsString = trend.getName().toString() + "\n";
                    }
                    trendingList.setText(trendsString);
                }
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });


}`
```

and here the analyze stacktrace

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                         at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1448)
>                         at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:102)
>                         at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:90)
>                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:787)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:200)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:148)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:90)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:190)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:142)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:104)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:392)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:325)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:489)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:435)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:566)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
>                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source:0)
>                         at twitter4j.HttpResponseImpl.(HttpResponseImpl.java:35)
>                         at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:149)
>                         at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
>                         at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:75)
>                         at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:2066)
>                         at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.getPlaceTrends(TwitterImpl.java:1912)
>                         at gusmappdev.myapp.TrendingActivity$1.onClick(TrendingActivity.java:77)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
>                         at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12693)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26100)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6942)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Hope you guys can help me :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the network access in another thread. It is not allowed to do network calls in the main application thread. That's why you get a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Here's a example how this can be solved: [How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to use the `getPlaceTrends()` method with `AsyncTwitter` instance. However in this case the method is `void` and I'm not sure how you can store the results.